# How to parse nested JSON to dataframe in R (or using an external tool)?

Tags: r, json, parsing, nested

I was trying to parse several JSONs on a dataframe on R, and I failed miserably.

The files were quite different. Some were quite simple and easy to parse (with library jsonlite), other were heavily nested and I got into much trouble to parse them. I eventually did it (very badly) but it was pain in the ass. And if I use another JSON with different nesting... It doesn't work anymore.

I googled quite a lot and I couldn't find any nice tool for that. There was tidyjson but it's not available anymore. On python with pandas it is simpler but I would like to stay with R.

**Question**: is there any library that you know of to do this? Or can you recommend an external tool to pre-process the JSONs and then load the result in R?

Thanks in advance! Cheers.

[Example JSON](http://history-data.urbanplatform.portodigital.pt/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:AirQualityObserved:porto:environment:ubiwhere:5adf39366f555a4514e7ea54?limit=10000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much delayed, but `tidyjson` is available again. Apologies for the trouble :) As the maintainer, I am pretty biased in my use of `tidyjson`, but it is my favorite tool for the job.

The `tidyr` and `purrr` packages have recently gained some helpful verbs for nested lists as well with `pluck`, `unnest`, `flatten`, `pivot_longer`, `pivot_wider`, and friends.

There is a whole article on the topic here:

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/nest.html